# Integrating DocuSign with iCims for offer management

Tags: docusignapi

We use a SaaS system called iCims for applicant tracking.  We have recently purchased the offer management module and want to integrate it with our DocuSign account.  iCims is asking for the following info - claiming not to need an API setup - to get us started:  Integrator Key, Public Key and Private Key.

DocuSign support is not being clear or helpful - I need to know the steps to go through to get started.  They sent me here.

Can anyone provide guidance?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and thank you for reaching out.

For information on how to obtain an integration key, public and private keys please see the following article:

https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-api-and-keys

The article walks you through how to obtain what you need.